# WUBI: can't get acces to data drive (D:\)

Tags: wubi, ntfs

Let me try to explain my situation.
Wubi installed on D:\ drive (data drive). And it seems ok, but i can't get acces to my D drive from Ubuntu (only C:\, Recovery and Boot are visible).
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Your Wubi host drive (in this case, D:) should be mounted on `/host`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wubi partition should be mounted on `/host`. Open nautilus and go to that directory to see this.

[Quoting directly from the FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_access_the_Windows_drives.3F)

> **How do I access the Windows drives?**
>
> The Windows partition where you installed Wubi is available as /host within Ubuntu (Places  Computer > File System > Host) All the other partitions will be available under Places > Removable Media